# gcp cloud command line cli not avaliable or not responding and when tutorial not accessable

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I cannot access google cli or google cloud command line console, the button for command line is not available and when I access via google cli in virtual machine access is still not available. Why this is a big deal because my Debian password is my vm id which is only accessible via google cloud command cli. also I cannot access google tutorial for no reason it's not just google tutorial not pop up but also when I search in google cloud I click on tutorial the tutorial still does not show. what is wrong? [image]

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem today on several users and we fixed it by clearing the browser caches / use incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and in incognito should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue in Google Cloud.

You can try the following workarounds:

- Using the [Cloud Shell URL](https://shell.cloud.google.com/%60) directly.
- Using Google Chrome in Incognito Mode.
- Using another Browsers.

The following actions will not help the issue.

- Logged out and logged in.
- Clearing Chrome cache.

*Update*

There is an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/223382987) that you can follow to see updates in the issue.

Comment: This is already reported in the status dashboard https://status.cloud.google.com/